# Does tip polarity still matter on modern electronics?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, power-supply

I have recently received an abandoned TP-LINK TL-WR741ND Wireless Router. It came with no antenna and no power brick.

I easily found an antenna replacement from a local electronic store.

Secondly, I also managed to find a multi-volt power brick for it. Now I just set it to 9 volts, and then I saw the polarity setting adjuster on the device like this one, and I left it at Positive Center.

[image: Click here for the img]

And I just crossed my fingers and hoped that it'll work, and viola! It did. I wonder, if I got that polarity setting wrong, how do I know?

Comment: "if I got that polarity setting wrong, how do I know?" - best case it wouldn't work at all. Worst case your router's fuse (or the router itself) would've melt / fired.

Comment: Yes; It still matters, electronics might be fancier but electricity hasn't changed

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of the Auto-MDIX feature that makes Ethernet crossover cables obsolete.  But that's a connection for data transfer.  That kind of interface smarts do not translate to a DC power interface.  The device (the wireless router) has no power (yet); it is dead.  You're trying to make the connection to power the device.  Even if it was possible for a device to auto-switch the polarity (but it can't since voltage is always relative), the device is currently without power, and therefore cannot do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can matter.

Most, but not all devices are center positive.  If you get it wrong, the impact can range from it not working to blowing up.  If its half-way decently designed it will simply not work.

The router probably does not have a fuse in it - if it has any kind of protective circuitry it would be a diode - these let current through 1 way but not the other, and don't generally die when they provide protection.  They are also smaller and cheaper.  Of-course, there is no guarantee there is one.